# How do I remove the space in the output of this regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I’m using regex in PHP. This is my script:

```
$s="2044 blablabla  2033 blablabla 2088";
echo preg_replace("/(20)\d\d/","$1 14",$s);
```

The result was like this:

```
20 14 blablabla 20 14 blablabla 20 14
```

I want to remove the space between the `20` and the `14` to get the result `2014`. How do I do that?

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do like this,

```
$s="2044 blablabla  2033 blablabla 2088";
echo preg_replace("/(20\d\d)/","2014",$s);
```

Comment: mmmm....you are hardcoding `$1` with `20`!???

Comment: he used this pattern `(20)\d\d` not `(\d\d)\d\d`

Comment: yes it works for this problem, it not general solution , thank for all

Answer (score 12):

You need to use curly brackets inside single quotes:

```
echo preg_replace("/(20)\d\d/",'${1}14',$s);
```

Answer (score 7):

After checking the `preg_replace` manual:

> When working with a replacement pattern where a backreference is
>   immediately followed by another number (i.e.: placing a literal number
>   immediately after a matched pattern), you cannot use the familiar
>   `\\1` notation for your backreference. `\\11`, for example, would
>   confuse `preg_replace()` since it does not know whether you want the
>   `\\1` backreference followed by a literal `1`, or the `\\11`
>   backreference followed by nothing. In this case the solution is to use
>   `\${1}1`. This creates an isolated `$1` backreference, leaving the `1`
>   as a literal.

Therefore, use

```
"\${1}14"
```

or

```
'${1}14'
```

Comment: new result like this 4 blablabla 4 blablabla 4

Comment: @ro0xandr Check the edit above.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte beat you by 8 secs...!! :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `preg_replace_callback()` function:

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/(20)\d\d/", function($number) {
    return $number[1].'14';
},$s);

// 2014 blablabla 2014 blablabla 2014
```